# Create a 2D array variable pointing to the same memory as an existing 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, aes

I am implementing AES for a school project. I have a function, aes_block, which accepts a one-dimensional array (length 16) of uint8_t as the message; I would like to encrypt this message in place. The first step is to map the bytes in[0], in[1], ... in[15] to a two-dimensional state array s[0,0], s[1,0], s[2,0], s[3,0], s[0,1], ..., s[3,3], as specified by FIPS 197. I tried to do that like this:

```
void aes_block(int keylen, const uint8_t *key, uint8_t *msg){
    uint8_t state[4][4] = msg;
    ...
}
```

allowing me to index into the state array by state[col][row].
This gave me a compiler error "invalid initializer"; how can I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Relatedly, I recommend signing the [Foot-Shooting Prevention Agreement](http://www.moserware.com/2009/09/stick-figure-guide-to-advanced.html) before getting too far into AES. :)

Comment: You can't change what an array is pointing at, or initialize it to point to a block of memory, since an array is not a pointer. Your options are to either make it a pointer, instead of an array, or copy the data from your original array.

Comment: Anyone interested in crypto, go read the comic behind the Foot-Shooting Prevention Agreement link in above comment of @ChristianTernus!

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to this is to just address the array differently.

Instead of `arr[i][j]`, you can use `arr[i*4+j]`.  The end result is the same, but there's no need to copy the array into a two-dimensional one.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint8_t (*state)[4] = (uint8_t (*)[4]) msg;
```

---

Explanation:

You want to reinterpret the bytes at `msg` as a 4-by-4 array of `uint8_t`. You could define `state` to be a pointer to such an array with this:

```
uint8_t (*state)[4][4] = (uint8_t (*)[4][4]) msg;
```

However, you would then have to access elements of the array with `(*state)[i][j]`.

Instead, we simply recognize that C normally converts an array to a pointer to its first element, and this makes array indexing work nicely. So we mimic that and do the conversion ourself: We declare `state` to be a pointer to the first element of the array-of-arrays. So, `state` is a pointer to the first array of four `uint8_t`. Then `state` may be used the way a normal array would be used: `state[i][j]` is the j-th element of the i-th array.

---

Note: If `uint8_t` is a character type, as it is in all normal C implementations for mainstream hardware, this reinterpretation is defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're assigning a pointer to a `uint8_t` to a two-dimensional array of `uint8_t`s, which is why you're getting that error.

You'll want to initialize the variable `state` separately, then use a `for` loop to assign `msg` to it one entry at a time.